# PHP Caching on Client or Server?

Tags: php, caching, memcached, apc

I was reading about PHP Cache (APC, MemCache, etc), suddenly a question raised in my mind

**The Caching in PHP is Done at which level?**

1. Either it is done on Client side or Server side?
2. Either on Hard Disk Space or Ram Space?

Any additional details or information about it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you have missed to tell us, what - after your sudden question - your research turned up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry if i missed something, but I am trying to gain knowledge on Caching and couldn't find this answer anywhere. Hence asked.

Comment: Well, then I would think about *why* you didn't find this answer anywhere.

Comment: I couldn't find it ...

Answer (score 3):

PHP caching is done on server side. It will be on hard disk obviously.

Comment: For the sake of pedantry; it will be stored in *persisted storage*; whether that's an HDD, SSD, RAMDisk, punch-paper, stones in a bowl...

Answer (score 1):

Basics of caching systems:

1. Install a caching system on your server (ie. memcached (http://memcached.org/))
   These caching services usually cache in memory.
2. Alter your code to work as: check for data in cache, if its not in cache, get it from file/webservice/database and store it in cache for X time.
3. On subsequent requests do the same thing, which will cause the data to come from the caching system instead of load heavy filesystem/webservice etc.

PHP has classes for most caching systems. Ie. http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php which will let you talk to your memcache server.

Installing memcached is quite easy btw, since its mostly 1 executable + 1 config file.